# In an FSA, can you have more than one transition for the same symbol from a single state?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

My textbook asks:

> Consider the sets of strings on $\{0,1\}$ where the 4th symbol from the right end is different 
>       from the leftmost symbol. Construct an accepting FSA.

The answer it provides is below. However, I don't understand how you can have one transition for *0*,*1* and another for *1* from the same state. What does this mean?
[image: answer to the problem]

Answer (score 2):

The FA in the image is an NFA as clearly a DFA cannot have more than one move for a symbol from a particular state. Also, it doesn't have any moves for state $q_5$ nor for $q_{10}$.

Comment: But in state q1, why are there two options for where to go if the symbol is '1'? How does this work?

Comment: Question asks to construct an accepting FSA(Finite State Automata) so it can be a DFA or a NFA, hence answer given as NFA. As it's easier to draw for this question.

Comment: @CasperC. You seem to be unfamiliar with NFAs, which are FSAs precisely allowing two or more transitions from the same state with the same label. A NFA accepts a string if there is _some way_ to move from the starting state to a final state using the input string. Note that there might be multiple paths you can take, but as long as at least one path reaches a final state, the string is accepted.